# How to return the highest number of an array while looping

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

How can I type-check and return the highest number of an array while looping? I can't get my code below to work.

```
var v = prompt("Enter a Value", "0");
var w = prompt("Enter a Value", "0");
var x = prompt("Enter a Value", "0");
var y = prompt("Enter a Value", "0");
var z = prompt("Enter a Value", "0");
var num1 = parseInt(v, 10);
var num2 = parseInt(w, 10);
var num3 = parseInt(x, 10);
var num4 = parseInt(y, 10);
var num5 = parseInt(z, 10);

var numArray = [num1, num2, num3, num4, num5];
var highest = 0;
for (var i = 0; i <= numArray.length; i++) {
    if (numArray[i] > highest) {
        highest = numArray[i];
    }
}

return(highest);
```

Comment: You might want to define more clearly what "not working" means. To start with, set `highest` to the first element of the array, then loop from the second. If you have only negative numbers your code is sure to fail.

Comment: Works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/5nq6b/ - are you supposed to be **returning** the results? That code as it won't give you any output as an alert would (in fiddle)

Comment: @Scrowler, it didn't work in my fiddle, now it does! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to do this:

```
var numArray = [num1, num2, num3, num4, num5];
var highest = numArray[0];
for (var i=1; i<=numArray.length; i++){
    if (numArray[i]>highest){
        highest=numArray[i];
    }
}

return(highest);
```

The difference is this: If you set `highest = 0`, you are discounting the possibility that the highest entered value is negative - so for `-1,-2,-3,-4,-5` as inputs, the return value would still be `0`. By saying "here is the first thing I look at: it is by definition the highest", then comparing the other values (second, third etc) to your "current best", you avoid that mistake. This kind of thing shows up in all kinds of places in software - very often "the first iteration" has to be a little bit different. In this case I took the first iteration out of the loop entirely, effectively.

Comment: Thanks very much Floris for helping, could you tell me what is the impact of changing to numArray[0] and var i = 1? It seems that the loop work both ways.

Comment: I have tried to explain why the small change to the loop makes a difference. Let me know if it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks again Floris for taking the time to explain it. It is still a bit vague, but I think I kind of get it. What about if it was var i=-1?

Comment: If you start counting from a negative index, you will create an error since there is no element `numArray[-1]` in your array. However you could write `for (var i=0;…) { if(var ==0 || numArray[i] > highest) highest = numArray[i];}` - "always update `highest` if it's the first element, or if the new one is bigger". Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 5):

You can simply do this:

```
var highest = Math.max.apply(null, numArray);
```